# Why are the values not being added to the PlayerPrefs file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save values to files in the `PlayerPrefs` for my mobile game in Unity however, the files do not update after playing the game.

```
public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private static gameManager instance;
    public static gameManager Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public int currentSkinIndex;
    public int currency  = 0;
    public int skinAvailability = 0;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("currency")) {
            // We had a previous session
            currentSkinIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("currentSkinIndex");
            currency = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("currency");
            skinAvailability = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("skinAvailability");
        } else {
            Save ();
        }
    }

    public void Save ()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currentSkin", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currency", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("skinAvailability", 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to update them with? The way I see it, you only save initial values of 0, 0, and 1 and never Save again after that.

Comment: What function would you suggest I use as I tried onApplicationQuit to use SetIn however that did not work.

Comment: This is because Android doesn't treat OnApplicationQuit() the way you would expect. It depends on your application, but you could either have a save button, save values when they are updated, save on screen change, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will give those a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic that you wrote has a problem! In `Awake()` you have two conditions => if there is key and if the is not!

You want to save some values to playerprefs and you have the save function already, but in `Awake()` you just call it under two conditions, here is what your code says:

1. Search through existing player prefs if the values exist, retrieve them
2. Or if they don't exist, then save them as I order to you to save them (inside save function logic => `currency = 0 , current skin = 0, skinAvailability = 1`)
3. Then do nothing. Keep in mind that all of this happens during `Awake()`

But the new values that you get after playing the game need to be saved too!
And you don't save them!

Your code *does not* say to "after I played the game (and the variables have changed), save the values *again.*"

You need to save them again! For example you can do that when exiting the play scene by writing a function or if you already written that function, you can assign it to a button which is been called `savebtn` which calls that function when clicked.